# List Collection Contains exact string

Tags: c#, list, generics

I have a List Collection and say that i am adding 3 items to them.

```
list.Add(new ContentDomain() {  Id = "1" , Content = "aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd"});
list.Add(new ContentDomain() {  Id = "2" , Content = "aa,bb,cc,dd"});
list.Add(new ContentDomain() {  Id = "3" , Content = "a,b,c,d"});
```

Now what i want is to fetch the rows that have just 'a' in the Content attribute.

Like i tried something like

```
list = list.Where(x => x.Content.ToLower().Contains("a")).ToList();
```

but that would give me all the three rows.

i want to search in a string for the exact string only.

Comment: what about x.Content.ToLower().Startswith("a")).

Comment: The thing is it can be any string in the list.. not only 'a'.. it can be 'b' or 'c' or 'aa' anything

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
list.Where(x => x.ToString().ToLower().Split(',').Where(a => a.Trim() == "a").Any()).ToList();
```

edit: Changed Count() > 0 to Any() for better performance

Comment: Wow that worked.. For my real purpose i had to to trim the string after the splitting i.e                                                  
.Where(a=>a.Trim().Equals("a")).Count() was used. Anyways Thanks a load for your help.. Keep Up the spirit...

Answer (score 0):

Convert it to an array of strings, and find the string in the array.

```
list = list.Where(x => x.Content.ToLower().Split(',').IndexOf("a")>= 0).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        IList<ContentDomain> returned = new List<ContentDomain>();
        foreach(ContentDomain myList in list)
        {
            var ret = myList.Content.Split(',');
            bool exists = (from val in ret
                          where val.Contains('a')
                          select true).FirstOrDefault();
            if (exists)
                returned.Add(myList);
        }
```